# create object from multiple selection option list and input

Tags: javascript, html

On click, user can dynamically add combo (select option + input field) into form with (city code and telephone number), need to retrieve in a object with the inputed values for these fields.

```js
//Code that retreive the input values:

var number_el = document.getElementById('phone').getElementsByTagName('input')
var telefoneNumber = [].map.call(number_el, function(input) {

  return {
    'telefone': input.value
  };

});

console.log(telefoneNumber);
```

```html
<div id="phone">
  <p>Telephone</p>
  <select name="city_code" id="telephone_1" class="telephoneList">
    <option value="1">212</option>
    <option value="2">216</option>
    <option value="3">215</option>
  </select>

  <input type="text" name="phone_number" id="phone_input1" value="555-222555"> </br>

  <p>Telephone</p>
  <select name="city_code" id="telephone_1" class="telephoneList">
    <option value="1">212</option>
    <option value="2">216</option>
    <option value="3">215</option>
  </select>

  <input type="text" name="phone_number" id="phone_input2" value="555-666555">
</div>
```

The above code retreive the input telefone:values in object.

I need to loop throw the select options to get its values and add to the object as show below:

Element name can be used as property name for both telefone and city_code.

```
telephoneList: [
  {
   "telefone":555-222555, 
   **"city_code":1**
  },
  {
   "telefone":555-666555, 
   **"city_code":2**
  }
]
```

Comment: Wrong markup with multiple elements with the same id

Comment: `selectElement.value` and `inputElement.value`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the attribute `previousElementSibling` for getting the previous element which is a `select`.

*This is assuming that the previous element is always the select `element`.*

```js
//Code that retreive the input values:

var number_el = document.getElementById('phone').getElementsByTagName('input')
var telefoneNumber = Array.from(number_el).map(function(input) {
  var object = {
    'telefone': input.value,
    'city_code': input.previousElementSibling.options[input.previousElementSibling.selectedIndex].value
  }
  
  return object;
});

console.log(telefoneNumber);
```

```html
<div id="phone">   <p>Telephone</p>   <select name="city_code" id="telephone_1" class="telephoneList">     <option value="1">212</option>     <option value="2">216</option>     <option value="3">215</option>   </select>    <input type="text" name="phone_number" id="phone_input1" value="555-222555"> <br>    <p>Telephone</p>   <select name="city_code" id="telephone_1" class="telephoneList">     <option value="1">212</option>     <option value="2">216</option>     <option value="3">215</option>   </select>      <input type="text" name="phone_number" id="phone_input2" value="555-666555">    </div>
```